# filter with two columns from datatable using queries

Tags: c#, linq, uipath

I want to get the data table which matches to values of two columns.

Initally i have used with single value which works fine.

```cs
in_dt_WPSFileInput.Select("PatientMedicareNumber='"+in_str_PatientMedicareNumber+"'").CopyToDataTable
```

when i want to add one more columns which is "DateofServiceStart"

```cs
in_dt_WPSFileInput.Select("PatientMedicareNumber='"+in_str_PatientMedicareNumber+"'") and ("DateofServiceStart='"+in_str_DateofServiceStart+"'").CopyToDataTable
```

it is throwing an error as complier error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJO8S.png)

Help me on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What language is the second line of code written in? That does not appear to be valid C#?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just filtering a DataTable using VB I would do the following:

```
in_dt_WPSFileInput.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(r) r("PatientMedicareNumber").ToString() = in_str_PatientMedicareNumber AndAlso r("DateofServiceStart").ToString() = in_str_DateofServiceStart).CopyToDataTable()
```